# Using XmlSerializer in Application startup

Tags: xml-serialization

I am looking at ways to improve the performance of serializing a certain object in my web service. This object has at a minimum 25 - 30 nested class objects with each having dozens of fields. And it can go up to 7-8 levels deep.

I've done some research on using XML attribute overrides and using FromTypes on the XML Serializer however they are not practical options for me given the number of nested classes and depth of this object. I do not own this object either since it generated from a web reference.

It takes about 5-7 seconds to serialize it the first time after which it very fast, down to milliseconds. I'm looking for ways to shift the cost of caching the objects during serialization from a service call to the application startup.

Is it a bad idea to create an XmlSerializer instance with the object type and throw it away just get those cache populated for the XmlSerializer?

So say I do something like:

new XmlSerializer(typeof(thisObject))

during the Application startup of a web service. I tried this approach and it brought down the cost of serialization during the service call for the first time down nearly 2 seconds.

Are there better alternatives (practical ones in my case)?

Comment: Take a look at [Boost performance with Pre-generated XmlSerializers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/02/02/boost-performance-with-pre-generated-xmlserializers.aspx) and [Use of SGEN.exe to avoid common XmlSerializer performance pitfalls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billwert/archive/2008/02/23/use-of-sgen-exe-to-avoid-common-xmlserializer-performance-pitfalls.aspx) and [All about XmlSerializer Performance and Sgen](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526956/All-about-XmlSerializer-Performance-and-Sgen).

Comment: Thank you for the links. The article was quite helpful and actually helped me. I experimented with the SGEN and was actually able to cut down up to 75% of the serialization time.